# Integrating Selenium Tests With Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse, testing, selenium, auto-generate

I have generated a Selenium test for testing a web service and exported that as a Java/Junit4/Remote Control test file. The file looks as follows :

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RemoteControl {

    private Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://rrrtttwwweee.com:8080/xxxx/vvvv/servers");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRemoteControl() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/boingo-object-model/vpn/servers");
        verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("{\"servers\":[{\"name\":\"automatic\",\"dns\":\"auto.ssl.boingovpn.com\"},{\"name\":\"us_west\",\"dns\":\"california.ssl.boingovpn.com\"},{\"name\":\"europe\",\"dns\":\"ireland.ssl.boingovpn.com\"},{\"name\":\"asia\",\"dns\":\"singapore.ssl.boingovpn.com\"}]}"));
        assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("{\"servers\":[{\"name\":\"automatic\",\"dns\":\"auto.ssl.boingovpn.com\"},{\"name\":\"us_west\",\"dns\":\"california.ssl.boingovpn.com\"},{\"name\":\"europe\",\"dns\":\"ireland.ssl.boingovpn.com\"},{\"name\":\"asia\",\"dns\":\"singapore.ssl.boingovpn.com\"}]}"));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

I now want to use this test file in my eclipse project. I know I will have to download a jar that contains `thoughtworks.selenium` somehow.

Wondering if someone already has experienced doing something similar before and if they know how to step through the process?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your project maven?

Comment: Nope, we build it using ant.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a `lib/` folder under your project's root folder.
- Download [Selenium's Java JARs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) and put them in that `lib/` folder.
- In Eclipse, go to `Project` -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Libraries` -> `Add JARs...` and add the JARs from the `lib/` folder.

This will enable Selenium inside Eclipse.

If you have an Ant script, don't forget to update it's classpath with something like this (assuming `${lib}` points to your `lib/` folder):

```xml
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">
    <classpath>
           <fileset dir="${lib}">
              <include name="**/*.jar" />
           </fileset>
     </classpath>
</javac>
```